# android webview using firefox render or engine

Tags: android, android-webview

My Web site is html 5 and if website open in firefox browser than it work very well. so is it possible to use firefox rendering engine or can i change default webkit or is there any third part library

Answer (score 1):

No. A website cannot decide what rendering engine should be used to render it. The best way is to fix your website so that it renders correctly on all major browsers.

Comment: i dont have problem with my web site ..its problem with android webview . if i open same website in firefox browser of android than it works very good but not in webview of android.

Comment: Also, firefox is not installed in android by default. So you cant choose it.

Comment: Thats odd because WebView and Chrome are both based on Chromium, what exactly is the problem your experiencing on WebView?